# Batch file to get computer name and insert character in it

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'll be having to change the names of 50 computers here soon and would like to make a batch file to make it easier. The computer name format goes as follows:
CMS-(RM#)-(TAG#) such as CMS-311-003784

I need to insert a T before the room number (CMS-T311-003784). I have this so far to change the name but I have to type the name in where it says NEWPCNAME.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell it to copy the current name but insert the T after the fourth character in the current name.

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d NEWPCNAME /f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the computer name like this, will try to figure out the way to insert a character at the right position, and edit this when I figure it out.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET host=%%i
echo oldname: %host%
if "%host:~4,1%"=="T" goto end
set host=%host:~0,4%T%host:~4%
echo newname: %host%
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %host% /f
:end
pause
```

EDIT

That was easier than I thougt, this takes substrings from the name and adds a T on position 4

Comment: This one appears to work in the command line, but doesn't ever change the name of the computer. It echos back the new host name but does not change it in the registry, or in computer properties. I even restarted and nothing?

Comment: EDIT-- this one changes the room number to 111 just like the post below does. CMS-T111-003784?

Comment: Yes, this code saves the computer name as a variable so you can use it in your own command to change the computer name using %host% as the new name

Comment: try this command again and see if it outputs the right oldname

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
if "%computername:~4,1%" neq "T" (
 echo REG DELETE HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName
 echo REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %computername:~0,4%T%computername:~4% /f
 set "computername=%computername:~0,4%T%computername:~4%"

)
echo Name changed to %computername%
pause
exit
```

Note that the required `"REG"` commands are `echo`ed - remove the `echo` keyword to activate.

Note that the original entry would most likely need to be deleted.

(untested) - verify before activating.

Comment: I tried this, it made the name 1T-111-003784. I changed the 1% in all three locations in the commands, and it makes the name 111-T111-003784. So it puts the T in the correct location, but why does it change the characters before and after the T? even if i change the name to CMS-333-003784, it makes it 111-T111-003784

Comment: Because I stuffed up the substringing. It should have been 0,4 (start at first character, for 4 characters - counting starts at "character 0") The first "4,1" is correct (**fifth** character in the string is **not** a "T" - this is intended as protection against "operation has already taken place". Perhaps `if "%computername:~14,1%" equ "" (` would be better (name is currently 14 characters long) `computername` is populated when `cmd` starts, so if you change the computer name, as you would for testing, you need to re-start `cmd`. Actually, I'll fix it to suit...